# Java RMI external jar

Tags: java, rmi

I am developing a demonstration in java using RMI, so I will have a server and a few clients connecting to that server.

I am currently doing this in UNIX, and opening these in terminals can be a bit tedious. 
I was wondering if it is possible to have the server in a jar and the client in another jar file. More specifically, do I need to take special precautions when specifying the class path for RMI etc ? What are the possible complications for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will normally have *three* JAR files:

1. Server code.
2. Client code.
3. Code that is common to both, e.g. the remote interface, the stub if you're generating them, and any classes that the remote interface depends on, and so on until closure.

(1) and (2) should name (3) in the Class-path entries of their Manifests.

Comment: So up until now I have: the server interface, the server implementation, the client and the server mainline which exports a stub representing the server interface. (Correct me if I am wrong)
So I need a jar for the Server Code, a Jar for the Client and a Jar for the stub?

Comment: Update: Solved it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Your comment merely reiterates what I had already said. I'm not fond of this procedure where I answer a question and am then asked to agree with a a more or less mangled paraphrase of my answer.